# Handling numbers with lot of values after decimal in Java

Tags: java, decimal

I do

```
 Collections.frequency(List<String>, List<String>.get(i)) / List<String>.size()
```

The output for the above calculation should be (for example)

```
0.00631
0.0002378
0.00571
```

but I get `0.0`, instead.
How do I handle this? I keep getting `0.0` with `double` and `float`

Thanks

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. Show some code, perhaps?

Comment: Where are you getting the 0.0? Debugger, console, file?

Comment: Especially considering those are not lot of values after the decimal when looking at it in scientific notation: `6.31e-3, 2.378e-4, 5.71e-3`. As-is, these values should not be causing issues, so we'll need more info.

Comment: You are using integers to make a division check aioobe's answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the values `0.00631`, `0.0002378` and `0.00571` are expected results from divisions, make sure you're not doing integer divisions. That is, make sure to cast numerator or denominator to float or double.

Instead of

```
double fraction = someInt / someOtherInt;
```

you can do

```
double fraction = (double) someInt / someOtherInt;
```

---

In your particular case, you could try something like

```
(double) Collections.frequency(list, list.get(i)) / list.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `BigDecimal` that does not introduce any rounding for very big or very small numbers at the cost of bigger memory consumption and slower computations. This class is a must for any financial data.

```
BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal("10000000000000.0002378");
System.out.println(val);
```

Comment: The OP has provided a bit more information, and `BigDecimal` seems unnecessary for what he's doing.